# Deployment of webforms solution in Azure

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, azure, deployment

I have a webforms solution. I publish it in Azure. I didn't modify the configuration by default of deployment to Azure

[image: publish]

I have a couples of problem :

- When I edit a config file and I deploy only the file edited ==> the file is changed but no modification in solution example if I change an url redirect rule !!!
- The preview of files before publishing makes a lot of time and show problems

I need to know :

- What are the best practises to deploy a webforms solution in Azure ?
- How  can handle the precompilation feature ?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please explain more about the No change? Do you mean you changed the web config file and publish it to the azure, but it doesn't change? Have you checked the web config file in the azure web app's kudu console?Besides, what do mean about the preview of files didn't work. Does this feature failed or show some error message?

Comment: @BrandoZhang-MSFT thank you for your reply :) I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

> When I edit a config file and I deploy only the file edited ==> the file is changed but no modification in solution example if I change an url redirect rule !!!

According to your description, I suggest you could firstly create a new wab app to check your web config's redirect rule setting is right. If you web redirect match rule is wrong, it will not show any exception when you run your web job.

Secondly, I suggest you could check the web app has already restarted after you published the web config.

You could find the web app's processid in the portal as below. If the web app has restarted the processid will be changed.

[image]

If the processid is changed and the webconfig setting is right, I guess azure web app server have cache. I suggest you could restart the web app.

[image]

> What are the best practises to deploy a webforms solution in Azure ?

In my opinion, if you develop your webforms solution in visual studio, I suggest you could use visual studio publish to azure to publish your project to web app.

Besides, I suggest you could update your visual studio azure SDK to the newest version. You could download from this [url](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/).

> How can handle the precompilation feature ?

Could you please explain more about this question? If you select publish the project in VS, it will precompile your Web site project automatic. If you want to use command line to precompile your Web site project,you could use Aspnet_compiler.exe tool. More details, you could refer to this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx#Performing%20Precompilation).